# Examples of harmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, regularity

I am looking for non-trivial examples (in the sense to be described below) of harmonic functions, which can be represented as cubes of smooth functions ($C^1$ would be also OK if this is important).

Thus, let us say that a harmonic function $u\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb C$ has a (smooth) cubic root, if there exist a smooth function $v\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb C$ such that $u=v^3$. If $n$ is even, it is easy to construct examples of such functions: Just take any holomorphic function $v$ and define $u:=v^3$.

Let us consider now the case of an odd $n$, say $n=3$. Some examples of harmonic functions admitting a smooth cubic root can be constructed as follows: Pick a splitting $\mathbb R^3\cong \mathbb R\times\mathbb C$ and a holomorphic function $v\colon \mathbb C\to\mathbb C$. For $(t, z)\in \mathbb R\times\mathbb C$ define $u(t,z):=v(z)^3$.

Some other examples can be constructed by separating variables, that is writing $u$ as a product of functions, where each multiplier depends on one or two variables only.

Are there any examples of harmonic functions $u$ on $\mathbb R^3$ admitting smooth cubic roots such that $u$ does not come from the two constructions above?

**Added:** If $u$ vanishes nowhere, it is always possible to take a smooth cubic root. The challenge is to construct examples with non-trivial (one-dimensional) zero loci.

Comment: In other words, you want solutions of the PDE $\Delta v^3=0$ or $2|\nabla v|^2 + v\Delta v=0$. I don't know anything about this, but it seems clear that there must be lots of solutions in addition to the ones you describe.

Comment: Anti-holomorphic functions are the obvious case you missed, same with functions holomorphic in some and anti in other arguments. Apart from that, I would turn the question on its head and look for roots of generic harmonic functions. In particular, if I am not mistaken as long as you are on a simply connected subset of $\{u\neq 0\}$, you can always define a smooth $\arg u$ and construct a (or rather 3) candidates for cubic roots, by $v := \sqrt[3]{|u|} e^{i(\arg u)/3 + k2/3 \pi}$. So the only interesting behaviour happens around those zeros, where some sort of degree 3 condition should apply.

Comment: @Christian Remling. Yes, absolutely correct. The only way I could come up with solutions of that equation is by separating variables, but this is not very interesting. Maybe I should have added, that particularly interesting would be explicit solutions.

Comment: @mlk Yes. Slightly more generally, we can compose a solution $u$ with any isometry of $\mathbb R^n$ and this yields further solutions. I guess this doesn't quite qualify as a substantially new solution.